# nasm can't call function in function

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

So I recently moved to nasm again and tried to build some basic stuff (putc and puts).

`Putc` works fine but the problem is that after I call `putc` in `puts`, the `ret` in `putc` does not return to the `ip` pushed onto the stack by `puts` and so no more instructions are being executed in `puts` (debugged that part in gdb).

```
msg db "Welcome!", 0ah, 0dh, 0h

putc:
    push ebp
    mov esp, ebp
    
    mov ah, 0ah
    ; al is set before
    mov bh, 0
    mov bl, 0
    mov cx, 1

    int 10h
    ret

puts:
    push ebp
    mov esp, ebp
    
    mov ebx, msg
    dec ebx
puts_l:
    inc ebx
    
    mov al, [ebx]
    call putc

    cmp al, 0h
    jne puts_l

    ret
```

It's clearly not the best but I think I have a misunderstanding somewhere. I could imagine that a register would be overwritten by putc but that doesn't clarify why the `ret` in putc does not return to `puts`

I should also mention as well that I'm working with x86.

Comment: You might be pushing ebp a few times too often. That could spoil the expectation of `ret` that the `ip` is the next item on the stack somewhat

Comment: That could actually make some sense. Tho, what do I do if I want to create stack frames? Thats as far as I know the way to do it. I thought ret would do the work for me to clear the stack frame. If not, I may have to use `leave`.

Comment: `ret` is just how x86 spells `pop ip` (or `pop eip` in 32-bit code).  It doesn't magically know where to return, [E/R]SP must already be pointing at a return address.

Comment: Yeah but shouldn't call push the current ip and then change the ip to the new address? That's what confuses me a bit about your comment.

Comment: Yes, `call` pushes the current `eip` (so called *return address*) and jumps to the called address, but the first thing at this address is your `push ebp`, so when you do `ret`, `eip` is loaded from this pushed `ebp`  instead of the expected *return addres* above it.

Comment: @vitsoft ah yes, that makes sense. I tried using the `leave` instruction which should solve this problem but the same problem occurs again. Why is that so? From my understanding, `leave` should `pop ebp`, basically redoing the `push ebp` and that should theoratically solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do

```
push ebp
mov esp, ebp
```

`esp` does not point to the pushed `ebp` and to the *return address* any longer, that's the problem which cannot be solved by using [LEAVE](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/leave) in the function epilogue. BTW `LEAVE` should be paired with [ENTER](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/enter).

If you really need the stack frame (e.g. to define a local memory variable), the skeleton might look like this:

```
Function:
    PUSH EBP    
    MOV EBP,ESP 
    SUB ESP,4   ; The local variable is now addressable as [ESP] alias [EBP-4].

    ; Here is the Function body which can use local variable(s).

    MOV ESP,EBP ; Discard local variable, ESP will point to the saved EBP. 
    POP EBP     ; Restore EBP which might be used as parent's frame pointer.
    RET
```

As your program does not use local variables, it could be

```
mov esi, msg       ; Address of the ASCIIZ string.
call puts          
jmp $              ; Program ends here.

puts: ; Function which displays ASCIIZ string at ESI.
    lodsb         ; Load AL from [DS:ESI], increment ESI.
    cmp al, 0h
    je puts_2
    call putc     ; Display a nonzero character in AL.
    jmp puts
puts_2: ret

putc:  ; Function which displays a character in AL.
    mov ah, 0ah ; WRITE CHARACTER.   
    mov bh, 0   ; Videopage 0.
    mov bl, 0   ; Colour in graphic mode.
    mov cx, 1   ; Number of times to write character
    int 10h     ; Invoke BIOS videofunction.
    ret

msg db "Welcome!", 0ah, 0dh, 0h ; The displayed ASCIIZ string.
```